# How to have mongo return just array within a field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Assume the following collection definition where the example is one entry in such a collection:

```
enumeration : {
    name: 'enumeration-1'
    elements: [
        {
            value: 'value-1'
            tags: ['tag-1', 'tag-2']
        },
        {
            value: 'value-2',
            tags: ['tag-2', 'tag'-3']
        },
        {
            value: 'value-3'
            tags: ['tag-3', 'tag-4']
        }
    ]
}
```

To return the specific enumeration is quite simple:

```
db.enumerations.find({ name: 'enumeration-1' })
```

However, I need augment that query to return only elements where each element has at least one tag in a list of tags. Consider the following parameters:

```
 1. name: 'enumeration-1'
 2. tags: ['tag-1', 'tag-4']
```

I need the output to be:

```
['value-1', 'value-3']
```

That is, I need only the value of the elements that have one or more of the specified tags that are contained within enumeration 1. What would the query look like, if at all possible? Returning the full element is fine as well. I am using Mongo 2.6.9.

Comment: I will correct the question accordingly. However, I did mean your first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework. The alternative in find queries is [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) or [$projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) both of which support only returning the first matching elements in an array so they won't work for your case since you want all value plus they won't work for your case anyways (I think). You need to filter by the array values but project something else.

But here is how it could work in aggregation framework (you can do all sort of things in the end if you need, e.g. make the results unique etc).

```
db.enumerations.aggregate(
 {$match:{"enumeration.name":"enum-1"}},
 {$unwind:"$enumeration.elements"},
 {$unwind:"$enumeration.elements.tags"}, 
 {$match:{"enumeration.elements.tags":{$in:["tag-1","tag-4"]}}}, 
 {$project:{"enumeration.elements.value":1}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work (going from memory), but seems like you need to look at $elemMatch for array query, and then look at the second optional argument to find, which is for projection.

```
db.enumerations.find({ name: 'enumeration-1', elements : {$elemMatch : { $in : ['tag-1', 'tag-4']}}}, {_id:0, 'elements.value':1})
```

Comment: This query I believe is close, but does not return any results. I am wondering if it is because there is no qualifer on the 'tags' attribute. I modified the query to look like this `db.enumerations.find({ name: 'enumeration-1', elements: { $elemMatch : { tags: { $elemMatch : { $in : { ['tags-1', 'tags-4'] } } } } } })`. That however returns all values (including value-2 which is not expected).

Answer (score 0):

You could run the following aggregation operation that uses [set operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-set/) as a hack (a dirty one) to produce the pruned elements array:

```
var query = {
    "name": "enumeration-1",
    "tags": ["tag-1", "tag-4"]
};

db.enumerations.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "name": query.name } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            "elements": {
                "$setDifference": [
                     {
                         "$map": {
                             "input": "$elements",
                             "as": "el",
                             "in": {
                                 "$cond": [
                                     {                                         
                                         "$setEquals": [                                                
                                             { 
                                                 "$setIntersection": [
                                                     "$$el.tags", query.tags
                                                 ] 
                                             },
                                             []
                                         ]                                           
                                    },                                     
                                     false,
                                     "$$el"
                                 ]
                             }
                         }
                     },
                     [false]
                 ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: @predhme Care to let me know why you unaccepted this answer? This will give me constructive criticism which will allow me to better frame my answer in the future.

Comment: When I originally accepted this answer, I tested inside the Mongo console and that worked fine for me. However, when I put the query into Jongo (our mongo framework), the query is not properly parsed, for no apparent reason. I searched their documentation and tried numerous things but the query failed when ran from Jongo. The java driver I am using is 2.6.9 which matches the Mongo verison. I am using Jongo 1.2.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: I certainly prefer this answer as the results come back precisely how I want them (from the mongo console). However, Jongo / mongo-java-driver do not seem to respect the $setDifference... My result looks like the following: `{ "name": "enumeration-1", "elements": { "$setDifference" : { ... } }`. I stopped at the set difference as it doesn't seem right that the query would return the expression... Not sure why it is not being evaluated by the framework.

Comment: Perhaps an upgrade is overdue?

Comment: I bumped the driver to the latest 2.X version and Jongo to 1.3 and that yielded no result.

Comment: Seems like using `$unwind` is the only option you have though since it produces a copy of each document per array entry you have to be wary that large arrays will use more memory due to the cartesian product (possible memory cap on aggregation pipelines of 10% total memory) and therefore also takes time to produce as well as time to process.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.enumerations.aggregate([
  { $match: {"name":"enumeration-1"} },
  { $unwind: "$elements" },
  { $unwind: "$elements.tags" },
  { $match: {"elements.tags": { $in:["tag-1","tag-4"] } }},
  { $group : { _id : null, values: { $push: "$elements.value" } } },
  { $project: {"_id":0, values:1}}
])
```

Output of this will look like

```
{
  "values" : [ "value-1", "value-3"]
}
```